# How to make a csv file with one column as file name and other as folder name

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

I am making a dataset, which is in a way such that for one thing like "apple" there is a folder named "apples" in the root folder(contains multiple folders) that contains only images of apples and so on.

I want to make a csv file in which it has all the filenames as one column and other as the folder name.

I tried this but it is entering data row-wise

```
from PIL import Image
import csv
import os
subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk('Training images')]
print(subdirs)
data=[]
with open('images.csv', 'w', newline='') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    for i in range(len(subdirs)):
        for filename in os.listdir(subdirs[i]):
            data.append(filename)
            writer.writerow(data)
            data=[]
writeFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), `writerow()` function can be used with lists. In your example, `data=[]` is the list and it is putted into `writerow()`.

You append only one item: `data.append(filename)`. Just append another: `data.append(dirname)`.

Or without temp variable `data` at all (recommended, less code = simpler to understand):

```py
    writer.writerow([filename, dirname])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply creates a directory structure for testing:

```py
import os

os.mkdir("root")
os.mkdir("root/apples")
os.mkdir("root/oranges")
os.mkdir("root/bananas")

for foldername in ["apples","oranges","bananas"]:
    for i in range(0,10):
        with open(os.path.join("root",foldername,f"{i}.txt"),'w') as f:
            f.write("test")
```

Now I loop through all folders in the `root` directory and append the names of the files within them along with their folder names into a list:

```py
list_ = []
for folder in os.listdir("root"):
    list_of_file_names = os.listdir(os.path.join("root",folder))
    list_ = list_ + list(zip([folder]*len(list_of_file_names), list_of_file_names))
```

This is what `list_` looks like:

```
[('apples', '0.txt'),
 ('apples', '1.txt'),
 ('apples', '2.txt'),
 ('apples', '3.txt'),
 ('apples', '4.txt'),
 ('apples', '5.txt'),
 ('apples', '6.txt'),
 ('apples', '7.txt'),
 ('apples', '8.txt'),
 ('apples', '9.txt'),
 ('bananas', '0.txt'),
 ('bananas', '1.txt'),
 ('bananas', '2.txt'),
 ('bananas', '3.txt'),
 ('bananas', '4.txt'),
 ('bananas', '5.txt'),
 ('bananas', '6.txt'),
 ('bananas', '7.txt'),
 ('bananas', '8.txt'),
 ('bananas', '9.txt'),
 ('oranges', '0.txt'),
 ('oranges', '1.txt'),
 ('oranges', '2.txt'),
 ('oranges', '3.txt'),
 ('oranges', '4.txt'),
 ('oranges', '5.txt'),
 ('oranges', '6.txt'),
 ('oranges', '7.txt'),
 ('oranges', '8.txt'),
 ('oranges', '9.txt')]
```

Finaly, I convert the above list to a pandas dataframe and save it as `csv` to a test file:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
```

The contents of the csv:

[image]